# Merging DataFrame Columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a special dataframe called df

here is how it looks like

```
RepID  +Col01  +Col02  +Col03  -Col01  +Col04  +Col05  -Col03  -Col04  +Col06  -Col07
1      5       7       9       8       3       8       1       9       4       6
2      1       3       3       3       1       2       2       3       6       0
3      9       8       0       9       4       9       5       1       2       0
4      3       1       0       5       8       7       1       0       9       2
5      0       7       1       2       0       0       2       9       2       1
```

They are all positive numbers in the data

but if you notice the column name it is a column name that is either with **+** or with **-**

Some of these columns have + with no columns with the - (Such as +Col06)

Some of these columns have - with no columns with the + (Such as -Col07)

Some other have both (Such as +Col01 and -Col01)

I want to make this dataset normalised by subtracting ting the value in the - columns from the + columns, and chnage the column name to a name with no + or - in the begining of the name, so the end table will look like this

```
RepID  Col01  Col02  Col03  Col04  Col05  Col06  Col07
1      -3     7       8     -6     8      4      -6
2      -2     3       1     -2     2      6      -0
3      0      8       -5    3      9      2      0
4      -2     1       -1    8      7      9      -2
5      -2     7       -1    -9     0      2      -1
```

Is there anyway I can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `groupby`, just extract the `+` and `-` columns separately, subtract with `fill_value=0`, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to the ID:

```
out = pd.concat([df[['RepID']],
                 df.filter(regex='^\+')
                   .rename(columns=lambda x: x[1:])
                   .sub(df.filter(regex='^-')
                          .rename(columns=lambda x: x[1:]),
                        fill_value=0)
                 ], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   RepID  Col01  Col02  Col03  Col04  Col05  Col06  Col07
0      1     -3    7.0      8     -6    8.0    4.0   -6.0
1      2     -2    3.0      1     -2    2.0    6.0    0.0
2      3      0    8.0     -5      3    9.0    2.0    0.0
3      4     -2    1.0     -1      8    7.0    9.0   -2.0
4      5     -2    7.0     -1     -9    0.0    2.0   -1.0
```

Comment: I think I have the `groupby` syndrome. Whenever it comes to combining things, it's the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem of subrtracting values and fix the column name and memory issue.
Thanks

Comment: Can it be done without the use RepID?

Comment: @asmgx yes, if you want to select all column without `+`/`-` in the beginning just replace `df[['RepID']]` by `df.filter(regex='^(?![-+])')`. If all columns start with `+`/`-` then just remove the `concat` part to only keep `df.filter(...).rename(...).sub(...)`

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

To extract the columns starting with "-", multiply the values by -1, and then group by axis=1.

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('-')]
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(-1)
grp = df.columns.str.replace('[+-]', '', regex=True)
out = df.groupby(grp, axis=1, sort=False).sum()
```

out

```
   RepID  Col01  Col02  Col03  Col04  Col05  Col06  Col07
0      1     -3      7      8     -6      8      4     -6
1      2     -2      3      1     -2      2      6      0
2      3      0      8     -5      3      9      2      0
3      4     -2      1     -1      8      7      9     -2
4      5     -2      7     -1     -9      0      2     -1
```

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'RepID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], '+Col01': [5, 1, 9, 3, 0], '+Col02': [7, 3, 8, 1, 7], 
         '+Col03': [9, 3, 0, 0, 1], '-Col01': [8, 3, 9, 5, 2], '+Col04': [3, 1, 4, 8, 0], 
         '+Col05': [8, 2, 9, 7, 0], '-Col03': [1, 2, 5, 1, 2], '-Col04': [9, 3, 1, 0, 9], 
         '+Col06': [4, 6, 2, 9, 2], '-Col07': [6, 0, 0, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: Groupby axis=1 is deprecated fyi

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option :

```
out = (
    df.apply(lambda s: -s if s.name.startswith("-") else s)
        .rename(lambda c: c.lstrip("+-"), axis=1)
        .T.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum().T
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   RepID  Col01  Col02  Col03  Col04  Col05  Col06  Col07
0      1     -3      7      8     -6      8      4     -6
1      2     -2      3      1     -2      2      6      0
2      3      0      8     -5      3      9      2      0
3      4     -2      1     -1      8      7      9     -2
4      5     -2      7     -1     -9      0      2     -1

[5 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this part .T.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum().T is giving error : MemoryError: Unable to allocate 13.1 GiB for an array with shape (37281, 47002) and data type int64, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way by using str.split() with expand=True to create a MultiIndex.

```
df2 = df.set_index('RepID')
df2 = df2.set_axis(df2.columns.str.split(r'(?=Col*)',expand=True),axis=1)
df2['+'].sub(df2['-'],fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   RepID  Col01  Col02  Col03  Col04  Col05  Col06  Col07
0      1     -3    7.0      8     -6    8.0    4.0   -6.0
1      2     -2    3.0      1     -2    2.0    6.0    0.0
2      3      0    8.0     -5      3    9.0    2.0    0.0
3      4     -2    1.0     -1      8    7.0    9.0   -2.0
4      5     -2    7.0     -1     -9    0.0    2.0   -1.0
```